# Custom game map working like Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I'm looking for a way to create a zoomable, draggable and customisable (add pins, draw trails, etc...) map using my own pictures (taken from various game maps).

I've found out about OpenLayers but I'm completely lost on how to use my custom files. I've also heard about tiles naming convention but I'm a bit lost too

Could someone provide some input on what external script I could use (does OpenLayers fit my needs?) and how should I get started?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IMO this is maybe a tad broad for SO and you'd better off with a tutorial or book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a pretty cool exemple of their Google Maps API on the moon. You can find it [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) and it should be enough to get you started. It's using custom images and the code is documented, have fun :)

I never used OpenLayers so I can't really help on that part, but you should try Google Maps first and see if It fits your needs. If not, you'll probably have more specific questions which OpenLayers might answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that Google APIs only work online. If you integrate them in a game, you will not be able to use it offline (even if you provide the map graphics).